# how to do dynamic file routing without express in node js?

Tags: node.js, https

I want to file routing in node JS without express to I want to return i.e.; if given path is directory so, show in UI like `...public` three dots and slash before directory name else if path is file so I want to show `index.html` in normal format

i have tried by this method but its showing error

```
if (path === '/' && method === 'GET') {

   
    const dir=fs.readdirSync("./",{
      encoding:'utf-8'
    });

    response.writeHead(response.statusCode, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });

    dir.map((element,index)=>{

      response.write(`
     <li><a href="./${element}" style="text-decoration: none;">${fs.statSync(`/${element}`).isDirectory()?`.../${element}`:`${element}`}</a></li>`)

    })

   return response.end();
  }
```

[file structure and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNyFK.png)